# Mixed types in np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to add data to a np array with mixed data, integers and strings. From [numpy.org](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#dtype)
i got:

> To use actual strings in Python 3 use U or numpy.str_.

However, if i use U or numpy:str_ if get

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fileA'

So I am pretty sure I misinterpreted somethine about the string or dtype. How do i get columns for strings in a mixed array in numpy? Thanks!

```
import sys
import numpy as np

document_dtype = np.dtype({'names': ['global_line','filename', 'file_line','type','text'], 'formats': ['i','U','i','U','U']})
document = np.empty(shape=(0,5), dtype=document_dtype)
document = np.vstack([document, np.array([2,'fileA',1,'Header','Test'],dtype=document_dtype)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'O'` for Python object.

In Python all data types inherit from `object`. So both strings and integers are objects.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the column to strings only? If i use `'O'` the error still occurs

Comment: No it shouldn't. All you have to do is replace: `document_dytpe = 'O'` and you won't get any errors.

Comment: If I replace all of the dtype i also lose the names and the integer values are not restricted to int anymore. Do you know of a way to keep the individual names and dtypes?

Comment: At this point I have no idea what you're trying to do. Please edit your question to make it more clear. Where is the mixed data? `"U"` should work for strings and `"O"` should work for anything.